# () missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I keep getting an error when trying to display individual items.
This is my code, i hope its understandable. I'm using django 1.11

1.my urls page:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
url(r'^about/', views.aboutus, name='aboutus'),
url(r'^specialoffers/', views.offers, name='offers'),
url(r'^contactus/', views.contact, name='contact'),
url(r'^excursions/', views.excursions, name='excursions'),
url(r'^singleexcursion/<int:id>/', views.singleexcur, name='singleexcur'),
url(r'^booking/', views.booking, name='booking'),
url(r'^confirmation/', views.confirming, name='confirming'),
url(r'^payment/', views.payment, name='payment'),
```

]

2. My views page:

   def singleexcur(request, id):
   excur = Excursion.objects.get(id = id)
   return render(request, "excursions/single.html", {"excur": excur })
3. my error:

   TypeError at /singleexcursion/int:id/
   singleexcur() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'

Comment: You "mix" `path` and `re_path` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way of handling  an empty id is to have multiple url for excursion:

```
 url(r'^singleexcursion/', views.singleexcur, name='singleexcur'),
 url(r'^singleexcursion/<int:id>/', views.singleexcur, name='singleexcur'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0), a new syntax was introduced, such that you can write parameters like `<int:id>`, but this is *not* applicable in `url(..)` constructs, here you need to write the path in a regex-like syntax, so you can specify the URL as:

```
# before Django-2.0

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^about/$', views.aboutus, name='aboutus'),
    url(r'^specialoffers/$', views.offers, name='offers'),
    url(r'^contactus/$', views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^excursions/$', views.excursions, name='excursions'),
    url(r'^singleexcursion/(?P<id>\d+)/', views.singleexcur, name='singleexcur'),
    url(r'^booking/$', views.booking, name='booking'),
    url(r'^confirmation/$', views.confirming, name='confirming'),
    url(r'^payment/$', views.payment, name='payment'),
]
```

Or in [django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0) and higher, you can use [**`path(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#path). You can interleave it with [**`re_path(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#re-path), which is the new name of `url(..)` since [**`url(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#url) will probably eventually get removed.

For example:

```
# Django-2.0 and above

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    re_path(r'^about/$', views.aboutus, name='aboutus'),
    re_path(r'^specialoffers/$', views.offers, name='offers'),
    re_path(r'^contactus/$', views.contact, name='contact'),
    re_path(r'^excursions/$', views.excursions, name='excursions'),
    path('singleexcursion/<int:id>/', views.singleexcur, name='singleexcur'),
    re_path(r'^booking/$', views.booking, name='booking'),
    re_path(r'^confirmation/$', views.confirming, name='confirming'),
    re_path(r'^payment/$', views.payment, name='payment'),
]
```

Comment: ..and when i change to this:
`url(r'^singleexcursion/(?P<id>\d+)/', views.singleexcur, name='singleexcur')`,

it brings this error:
`Reverse for 'singleexcur' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['singleexcursion/(?P<id>\\d+)/']`

Comment: @NegritaDevelopers: that is because you have defined a `{% url 'singleexcur' %}`, or a `redirect('singleexcur')`, etc. but *without* an `id=some_id`, so now that path makes no sense anymore.

Comment: Should that be added to the views?
Its more like this:
`<a class="product__btn-book btn btn-secondary btn--round" href="{% url 'profiles:singleexcur' %}">book
                                        now</a>`

Comment: @NegritaDevelopers: you should replace the `href="{% url ... %}"` with `href={% url 'profiles:singleexcur' id=some_id %}"` with `some_id` a variable that proves the `id` of the `Excursion` to "book".

Comment: I have changed it..the error is still there:
`Reverse for 'singleexcur' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['singleexcursion/(?P<id>\\d+)/']`

Comment: @NegritaDevelopers: then there are more `{% url ..%}`s, `redirect(..)`s, `reverse(..)`s that suffer from the same. You should look at the traceback to see where this originates from.

Comment: Sadly, nothing helped. I have tried everything i could possibly think of..

Comment: @NegritaDevelopers: take a look at the *traceback* the line where the "reverse URL" is generated will be *in* the traceback, so then you know what you need to fix.